# Group a row sequence (before & after an event)

Tags: r

I have a data frame with dates of patient-checkup's (c) and injections (i)

`Pat Date ID Visit 
1,d 2016-01-25 122 c
1,d 2016-04-26 213 i
1,d 2016-05-23 274 c
1,d 2016-08-31 201 c
1,d 2016-10-25 223 i
3,s 2015-05-26 123 c
3,s 2015-07-01 450 i
3,s 2015-07-21 234 c
3,s 2016-01-13 345 i
3,s 2016-02-22 278 c`

I'm only interested in a total Set of:
a pre-checkup, 
an injection and 
a post-checkup (c-i-c).

But it is also possible to use a post-checkup from one injection as a pre-checkup for a following injection. That's the plan how it should look like, with the checkup-id's before and after an injektion

`Pat Date ID Visit Before-ID After-ID
1,d 2016-01-25 122 c
1,d 2016-04-26 213 i 122 274
1,d 2016-05-23 274 c
1,d 2016-08-31 201 c
1,d 2016-10-25 223 i 201 0
3,s 2015-05-26 123 c
3,s 2015-07-01 450 i 123 234
3,s 2015-07-21 234 c
3,s 2016-01-13 345 i 234 278
3,s 2016-02-22 278 c`

Thank you for any idea you can offer in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach. For each patient whenever there is an injection row we get the previous and the next visit ID, if they exist, and if they don't exist we use `0`. If there is a non-injection row then we use `NA` values.

```
df = read.table(text = "
Pat Date ID Visit 
1,d 2016-01-25 122 c
1,d 2016-04-26 213 i
1,d 2016-05-23 274 c
1,d 2016-08-31 201 c
1,d 2016-10-25 223 i
3,s 2015-05-26 123 c
3,s 2015-07-01 450 i
3,s 2015-07-21 234 c
3,s 2016-01-13 345 i
3,s 2016-02-22 278 c
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Pat) %>%
  mutate(Before_ID = ifelse(Visit == "i", lag(ID, default = 0), NA),
         After_ID = ifelse(Visit == "i", lead(ID, default = 0), NA)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#   Pat   Date          ID Visit Before_ID After_ID
#   <chr> <chr>      <int> <chr>     <int>    <int>
# 1 1,d   2016-01-25   122 c            NA       NA
# 2 1,d   2016-04-26   213 i           122      274
# 3 1,d   2016-05-23   274 c            NA       NA
# 4 1,d   2016-08-31   201 c            NA       NA
# 5 1,d   2016-10-25   223 i           201        0
# 6 3,s   2015-05-26   123 c            NA       NA
# 7 3,s   2015-07-01   450 i           123      234
# 8 3,s   2015-07-21   234 c            NA       NA
# 9 3,s   2016-01-13   345 i           234      278
#10 3,s   2016-02-22   278 c            NA       NA
```